# How to select distinct values from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with SQL Server database and I have a table called `companiesData` with three columns: `id, name, projects` I want to get the values from the `id` and `name` without the repeated values.

Content of the tables:

```
| id      | name      | project      |
| 1       | Company A | Project A    |
| 2       | Company B | Project A    |
| 3       | Company B | Project B    |
| 4       | Company A | Project B    |
```

If I write:

```
select distinct name from companiesData;
```

The query returns:

```
| name      |
| Company A |
| Company B |
```

But like I said in the beginning I want the data from two columns of the same table (I only have one right now). So I write the next query to get the data:

```
select distinct id, company from companiesData;
```

And it returns:

```
| id      | name      |
| 1       | Company A |
| 2       | Company B |
| 3       | Company B |
| 4       | Company A |
```

So, I also tried with:

```
select id, company from companiesData group by id, company;
```

But this returns the same data of the second query. In others questions the answer to this problem is use `distinct` or `group by` but this is not working for me.

Is there any other way to get this data? Am I wrong in my queries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "1, Company A" and "4, Company A" are not the same, so it makes sense that they would both show up when you use `distinct` or `group by`. If you only want one row returned for "Company A", you need to decide which id you want. If you don't care, try something like `select max(id), company from companiesData group by company`

Comment: @EdmCoff So if two "Company A" have the same name but they have a different ID, are different?

Comment: Yes, when using distinct (or group by without aggregate functions) all of the columns selected need to be the same for a row to be eliminated from the result.

Comment: And what could be a good solution because the accepted answer will no work with three or more columns becuase the will have to be added inside the `group by` statement and will send repeated data

Comment: If you only care about the `company` column being distinct, you can put min/max on all the other columns and just group by `company.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want "Company A" to appear once in your results, with one of the ids, and you don't care which one?   How about:

```
select min(id), company from companiesData group by company
```

Comment: Yeah! This is working but can you explain me please why the distinct and group by are not working because they are accepted answer in a lot of questions like this

Comment: @JorgeNajera distinct and group by won't work because you included ID which is unique and not repeated.